# Semiprime asymptotic step function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, semiprimes

Since
$$\pi_{(2)}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\pi(x^{1/2})}\left(\pi\left(\dfrac{x}{\text{p}_i}\right)-i+1\right),$$
where $\pi_{(2)}(x)$ denotes the semiprimes and $\text{P}_i$ is the $i$th prime, an asymptotic of the semiprimes may be given by
$$\pi_{(2)}(x)\sim R\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)+\sum_{i=2}^{R(x^{1/2})}\left(R\left(\dfrac{x}{R^{(-1)}(i)}\right)-i+1\right),$$
where$$\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\log(t)}\operatorname{d}t,$$
$$R(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}),$$
and the inverse of $R(x)$ is approximated by the Halley iterations
$$p(n,i)=n-\dfrac{2n\log(n)(R(n)-i)}{2n+R(n)-i} $$
$$\Rightarrow R^{(-1)}(i)\approx p^{(3)}(i\log(i),i)\sim\text{P}_i.$$
This is a step function however, which can be smoothed in a piecewise fashion with a sawtooth function at $R(x^{1/2})=\text{Int.}$ as follows:

[image]
[image]

Is this smoothing valid for all $x$?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106130/counting-functions-or-asymptotic-densities-for-subsets-of-k-almost-primes

Comment: @draks .. +1) :)

Comment: ...what is $p^{(3)}$? Third derivative?